# How to fetch type of form collection values in mvc

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, formcollection

I have a form that sending to controller with ajax after serializing. I want to fetch the values type as int or string in controller.The form has input type text and input type number? how can i fetch the type of input type number as int ?
Controller code as below

```
 string abc = fm[key].GetType().Name;
```

This is getting always 'String'.

Assume you have a form in view as below

```
<form method='Post' action='../Home/Index'>
  <input type="text" name="First"/>
  <input type="number" name="Second"/>
  <input type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

In controller side looping the keys and values and adding them to the stored procedure parameters. But the sp has also a parameter as type such as string,integer...

The controller as below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection fm)
{
    foreach (var key in fm.AllKeys)
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new  SqlCommand("SysDefinitionPopulate", con))
        {
            string abc = fm[key].GetType().Name;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@key", key);
            command.Parameters.Add("@value", fm[key]);
            command.Parameters.Add("@type", abc);
            command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FormCollection` is a special dictionary both keys and values of which are strings.

To get integer you can create a custom model and instead of 'FormCollection' use this model, e.g.:

```
public class MeaningfulName
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public int Second { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MeaningfulName model)
{             
     using (SqlCommand command = new  SqlCommand("SysDefinitionPopulate", con))
     {
         command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         command.Parameters.Add("@key", model.First);
         command.Parameters.Add("@value", model.Second);
         command.ExecuteScalar();
     }
}
```

Comment: Ok then, i will try sth different. After search i saw this. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Better not use FormCollection - use Model Binding instead!

E.g. simple binding like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string First, int Second)
{
    // do your magic
}
```

Or using an actual model class:

```
public class TestModel // put in Models folder
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public int Second { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(TestModel myData)
{
    // do your magic
}
```

Comment: Thanks your suggestion but my view taking List<dynamic>. I want to do it as you answer a lot :) but sometimes the condition can be different.